# disabling an input button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable this button on document ready but I'm new to it so please help:

Here is my code:

```
   $(document).ready function {
setTimeout("check_user()", 250);
}
```

please help

Comment: Where is the HTML with the input button you want to disable?

Comment: What button?  Please post the relevant HTML code containing the button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If button's id is button1, this should work.

```
$('#button1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: need to wrap it like this $(document).ready(function(){$('#button1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

Comment: @samccone the OP demonstrated that he already knows about `$(document).ready()`.

Answer (score 2):

The *correct* way to disable a button in current versions of jQuery is:

```
$('#btnid').prop('disabled', true);
```

`.attr()` is the old way.  See the [jQuery 1.6.1 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/) for more information.

Comment: it has messed up semantics due to it being a value-less attribute.  `.prop` works better.

Comment: also, attributes are mostly about the default "onload" state of the element - properties reflect their _current_ state.

Comment: @Alnitak: _"The .prop() method should be used for boolean attributes/properties and for properties which do not exist in html (such as window.location). All other attributes (ones you can see in the html) can and **should** continue to be manipulated with the .attr() method."_ (emphasis mine). They handle different sections, although with some overlap. Setting the attribute with `$.attr('disabled', true)` is not a correct way maybe, however `$.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` should always work.

Comment: @Shef see higher up in the release notes - `disabled` *is* one of the _boolean_ attributes, so should use `.prop()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnId').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#buttonclass').attr('disabled', true);
});
```